# Join value to string in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects in TypeScript(Angular), and I want only names from this array if details array is not empty

```
 [
  {name: "Joe", detail: []},
  {name: "Kevin", detail: [{salary: 2400}] },
  {name: "Peter", detail: [{salary: 2100}]}
]
```

I want this result Kevin,Peter in one variable

Currently I have done this

```
 [
  {name: "Joe", detail: []},
  {name: "Kevin", detail: [{salary: 2400}] },
  {name: "Peter", detail: [{salary: 2100}]}
].map(function(elem){
return elem.name;}).join(",")
```

Can anyone help me to do this in Typescript or JavaScript?

Comment: check out [Array#filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  { name: "Joe", detail: [] },
  { name: "Kevin", detail: [{ salary: 2400 }] },
  { name: "Peter", detail: [{ salary: 2100 }] },
];

const filteredArray = array.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.detail.length > 0;
});

const result = filteredArray.map((obj) => obj.name).join(", ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Don't need to loop 2 times like this, bro.

Comment: @Phong I've read your answer and it's perfect. Imran is a new contributor so I thought we should help him to give him as many options as we can.

Comment: @Phong That's very much to preference, and a tradeoff between performance and readability/maintainability. I find `array.filter(obj => obj.details.length > 0).map(obj => obj.name)` more clear than your approach with `reduce` *(and I've written code like that myself in the past)* or if you don't want to loop twice over the array, I'd still go with a loop `const result = []; for(const obj of array) if(obj.details.length > 0) result.push(obj.name);` *(properly formatted)* over of the reduce. But as I said, it's personal preference.

Comment: @Thomas very true but compatibility is a problem with for...of loop. As it is not supported by [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and every Array methods are compatible with all browser.

Comment: @DeC This issue died a few years ago with the spread of build-pipelines and [transpilers](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want Joe in the result because `Joe's detail` is empty. I only
> want `kevin,Peter`

You can use `.reduce` combines with `destructure object` like below to resolve it.

```js
var data =  [
  {name: "Joe", detail: []},
  {name: "Kevin", detail: [{salary: 2400}] },
  {name: "Peter", detail: [{salary: 2100}]}
];

var result = data.reduce((acc, {name, detail}) => {
  if(detail.length > 0) acc.push(name) // condition to add name into result   
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result.join(","));
```

Comment: I do not want Joe in result because Joe details is empty. I only want kevin,Peter

Comment: Updated my answer, pls take a look at ^^!

Comment: Is there any better approach we can do in Angular

Comment: Oops. It's the same. The original is `Javascript` code instead of the `framework` or `library`, bro :)

Comment: concise and efficient answer.